# Get store id of the current user logged in admin

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, stores, acl

How can i get store id of the current user logged in admin in magento? 
I want to restrict custom module data by the type of user logged in admin area. I followed below link http://www.pixelpaul.net/magento-restrict-admin-order-website-store-view-certain-user-role/

I have also used Amasty Advanve permission but it doesn't work for custom module

Comment: For magento 2 or magento 1?

Comment: Have your try this code => $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();?  It is return admin store id

Comment: yes it gives me 0 which is incorrect

Comment: Yes it is correct. Because admin store id is zero

Comment: You want to get the `storeId` of current admin user in front of back ?

Comment: The thing is i created a store arabic & also an admin user for only arabic store. now i want him to access data of only arabic store. Arabic store is different website. For my custom module

Comment: try this extension https://amasty.com/magento-advanced-permissions.html

Comment: I have used but doesn't work for custom module

Comment: have you created acl for the custom module?

Comment: yes  i have created Acl. The issue is in displaying grid data

Comment: Ok. have you set roles Resourece for  this user. Please check screen shot   https://amasty.com/v1539257117/media/catalog/product/cache/1/screenshot/040ec09b1e35df139433887a97daa66f/magento-advanced-permissions-restrict-category-creation.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84331/discussion-between-abdul-and-arjun).